# how to move an app with the same bundle identifier to another apple developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, apple-developer

so currently I am developing an app with certain bundle identifier. previously I use one apple developer account, and we plan to change the apple developer account associated with this app.

when I change the 'team' to the new apple developer account like this:

[image]

then I get an error like this:

> Failed to create provisioning profile. The app ID "xxxxx" cannot be
>   registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to
>   a unique string to try again.
>
> No profiles for 'xxxxx' were found Xcode couldn't find any iOS App
>   Development provisioning profiles matching 'xxxxxxx'.

it seems that I have to change the bundle identifier. I don't want to change the bundle identifier.

I have tried to inspect in my previous apple developer account, I thought that i have to delete something related to the bundle identifier in that previous apple developer account, but I can't find it (maybe I don't know where the file that needs to be deleted)

what should I do if I want to use the same bundle identifier app but change the apple developer account ?

I little bit confused here,

[image]

when I first develop the app, I don't have paid apple developer account for my company, I just use the free account, and this app is associated with that Personal Team (ads IT solution), my apple ID for this Personal Team let say is xxx@gmail.com,

and then with this same apple ID (xxx@gmail.com) then I enroll as organization (my company).

but when log in to this organization account, I can't the bundle identifier on the App IDs section.

it seems the free account and the paid account seems different. and it seems this bundle identifier is associated with that personal account (free account)

I don't know how to access that persoanl team account, because when I login using the same apple ID, I will be directed to the organization account

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the App ID from your developer account.

Comment: @Paulw11 I can't find it on the App IDs section, maybe I am confused between personal account and organization account. I have added some information on my question above, really need your help. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue.

1. Go to your Apple developer account where the app is currently registered.
2. Click "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" on the left column.
3. Click `Identifiers` on the left column.

[image]

4. Click on the row with the identifier you want to use on your new Apple account.
5. Click "Remove" on the top right.

[image]

6. Confirm that you would like the identifier and profile to be removed everywhere

You should now be able to click "retry" in xCode, and the identifier will be able to link with your new account.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot locate your step 2

Comment: Oh, I now see it. Thanks bro. Works fine

Comment: @calistus. I couldn't locate step 2. I don't have a paid account and I would like to change for my paid account. How can I go there from my free account?

Comment: @DavidL I think you require a paid account for this

Answer (score 2):

Its an old post... But if it helps someone...

I had run into this issue and followed the below approach which is an alternative without going to website.

Basically I opened the project in xCode with the old Team Information. Then changed the Bundle ID for that to a different random value.

Once this change got applied... the previous bundle id became free and available. Then I was able to use it for the new Account's Team Bundle ID.

Of course it was easier for me since I had 2 Macs. One logged in with the Old User Account and the other logged in with the New User Account. You may need to switch between the Accounts if you only have one device to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer apps via AppStoreConnect. Apple's help page: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f. Select your app, go to the App Store > App Information tab and you can scroll down and see it.

However, there's a good chance you won't find a button there because it doesn't meet the criterion of **"The App must have had at least one version that has been released to the App Store"** per their requirements at https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devaf27784ff. Just having it in there for testing *does not* count. I still haven't found a way around this.

You can open up the browser's inspector while on the App Information tab, find the link "/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/LCAppPage/transferApp?adamId=xxxxxxx" (don't search with the x's) and remove the class ng-hide from its parent node, and click on the button to see which criteria your app fails to meet.

A side note, based on a comment: if you remove the app from your account it won't help because the AppID still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds weird, but the way I found was to **call to Apple Developer Program Support**, then they helped me unassign it from the first account to make it  "bundle identifier" available to the second account.

It was very effective because I couldn't access to AppConnect from my first account due it's a free one.